# High School physics/Kinematics/ statics question

Tags: physics, kinematics

A block rests on a plane which is inclined at 35 degrees. A force $F_b$ is applied to it at an angle of 40 degrees to the plane. $F_g = 980$ Newtons is the force due to gravity and $F_n$ if the normal reaction. See diagram. What are the steps that I would need to take in order to calculate what $F_b$ would be if the mass is at equilibrium?
It's difficult for me to calculate it because $F_n$ changes when $F_b$ changes
Assume that there is no friction

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$F_gsin(35)=F_bcos(40)$

you can calculate $F_b $ from the above equation

$F_gcos(35) - F_bsin(40) = F_n$

You can calculate The normal force $F_n$ fropm this.

Answer (score 0):

$F_gcos55 = F_bcos40$

$F_b = \frac{F_gcos55}{cos40}$

Comment: I don't think it's that simple, f_b effects to total normal force experienced by the mass, because of this the net resultant force down the slope would be different as well.

Comment: *resultant force down the slope” not net resultant force

Comment: If you tilt the x-y axis to the normal force direction, then the $F_x$ will yield the above relationship. For the mass to be in equilibrium, the net $F_x$ should be equal to zero.

Comment: So, if we make the direction of normal force the "y" direction and the slope if the plane the "x" direction, then the "y" component of F_b would be 733.78sin(40)~ 471.66, the normal force due to gravity will be given by 980cos(35) which gives ~ 802.77. Take away the "y" component of your F_b from the Normal force by F_g gets you ~ 331.11N we can use this to find what would be the force down the slope if we ignore the "x" component of F_b with is 331.11tan(35) which gets us 231.84. Comparing this to the "x" component of F_b which is 733.78cos(40) and that gets us ~ 562.10. They are different.

Comment: I try to think if of this way, let's say that you are pulling a box across the ground, if you pull the box upwards a bit you would not need to pull is as much forward compared to pulling it in the direction parallel to the ground.

Comment: Is that way of thinking correct?

Comment: The normal force is the resultant force that takes into consideration $F_b$ and $F_g$.  Look a the other responder's solution. That is correct too. Since you wanted $F_b$.  I restricted my analysis to $F_x$.  I don't follow your argument.  As far as your comment about the direction of pulling force you can susbstitute angle to be zero, you will figure it out